# Is there any way to create a table in existing dataset? Power BI REST API

Tags: powerbi

I am not able to find any information on how to create a new table in existing data sets using REST api.

How to get list of tables for existing data set.
Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 2):

that's not a supported feature right now.  Could you make submit this through our support site so we can track this request and keep you updated if we add this capability?

https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi

Appreciate your using Power BI,
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Make a feature request: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request here:
https://support.powerbi.com/forums/268152-developer-apis/suggestions/7111791-alter-datasets-by-adding-removing-individual-table

It'd be great if the PowerBI team allowed to post tables to an existing dataset through the API.